# Want to load .cache.html file of GWT application on client side

Tags: html, apache, gwt

I want to load .cache.html file of GWT application on client side ( Browser )

but now when I load my application on browser each time .cache.html file is downloaded from the server

I don't want it to be downloaded on each request , because it's too heavy

Please suggest me solution

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GWT documentation includes [example cache settings for .htaccess on Apache](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#perfect_caching).

```
<Files *.nocache.*>
  ExpiresDefault "access"
</Files>

<Files *.cache.*>
        ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 year"
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your server to tell the client to cache that file. All the files with 'cache' in their filename should be configured that way.

Comment: can u please tell me the configuration that I need to do ?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Apache from the tags you've used. I don't know Apache config, I'm afraid. There should be loads of example on the web. I'd Google for "Apache GWT cache" or something.

Answer (score 1):

It can get a little tricky when you have apache serving as proxy for tomcat. [Here is how I am doing it](http://pgt.de/2011/01/27/apache-configuration-for-gwt-applications/).